# Array as a dictionary value in swift language

Tags: swift

I have the following swift dictionary

```
var List = [

   2543 : [ "book", "pen" ],
   2876 : [ "school", "house"]
]
```

How can i access the array values ?

```
println(List[2543][0])
```

The above code gives error "could not find member subscript"

and it should print "book"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that `subscript` returns an optional. We have to force unwrapping:

```
println(list[2543]![0])
```

Or use optional chaining

```
println(list[2543]?[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
println(list[2543]![0])
```

Remember, dictionary subscript returns an Optional, not an array or whatever is inside the dictionary value.

Comment: The important thing to understand is that Optional is itself a type (an enum). It contains a value (or nil) inside itself, but you cannot talk directly to it as if it were the value.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with following code:

```
var dic = List[0];
println("values \(dic)")
```

**OR**

```
println(list[2543]![0])
```