# add multiple key and value in Dictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I want to add multiple value in `NSDictionary`. They make me trouble.
I am newer in Swift.

```
 m=NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys:[self.getStringAt(selectStmt, column: 0)],"first",[self.getStringAt(selectStmt, column: 1)],"second",nil)
```

Comment: you can pass value as a array in dictionary.

Comment: Do you want to add multiple values to one key or do you want to add multiple key-value-pairs at once?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
let interestingNumbers = [
                            "Prime"     : [2,3,5,7,11,13],
                            "Fibonacci" : [1,1,2,3,5,8],
                            "Square"    : [1,4,9,16,25]
                         ]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Simply key is string, and value is array. And there is how you can access elements on this structure: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097564/array-as-a-dictionary-value-in-swift-language)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Collection Types: Dictionary */

var dic1 = ["math":89, "chemistry":90, "physics":79]


// Modifying

dic1["math"]
dic1["math"] = 70   // returns new value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *eventLocation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"43.93838383",@"latitude",@"-3.46",@"latitude" nil];

NSMutableDictionary *eventData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:eventLocation,@"eventLocation", nil];
[eventData setObject:@"Jun 13, 2012 12:00:00 AM" forKey:@"eventDate"];
[eventData setObject:@"hjhj" forKey:@"text"];
.
.
.
NSMutableDictionary *finalDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:eventData,@"eventData", nil];
[finalDictionary setObject:@"ELDIARIOMONTANES" forKey:@"type"];
[finalDictionary setObject:@"accIDENTE" forKey:@"title"];
```